# Use a variable within a plotmath expression

Tags: r, plotmath

I'm trying to place the results of a regression (i.e., R2) in a graph, but can't seem to figure out how to call a variable from within an expression (it pastes the variable name).

Here is my code.

```
R2Val <- signif(summary(sMod_pre90)$r.squared[1], 2)
text(92, 4, expression(paste(R^2, " = ", R2Val)), adj = 0, cex = 0.85)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `bquote()`. Here is an example with dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(A = rnorm(100), B = rnorm(100))
mod <- lm(B ~ A, data = DF)
R2Val<-signif(summary(mod)$r.squared[1], 2)
```

The parts of the expression wrapped in `.()` get evaluated in the environment, i.e. the value of `R2Val` is substituted.

```
plot(B ~ A, data = DF)
text(1.5, 2, labels = bquote(R^2 == .(R2Val)), adj = 0, cex = 0.85)
```

Another potential solution is `substitute`, which works similarly:

```
plot(B ~ A, data = DF)
text(1.5, 2, labels = substitute(R^2 == A, list(A = R2Val)), adj = 0, cex = 0.85)
```

Answer (score 1):

To combine `substitute()` and `paste()`, I use the following code;

```
waic <-1;
chisquare <-2;
plot(x=1:2,y=1:2, 
     main =  substitute(paste(
    "chi^2 goodness of fit ", 
       chi^2*(D/theta) , "=",  chisquare ,
       ".  WAIC =",waic),


list(chisquare=chisquare,waic=waic)  
)
)
```

The result is the following;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to put it together using the substitute function.

```
R2Val <- signif(summary(sMod_pre90)$r.squared[1], 2)
text(92, 4, substitute(R^2 ~ "=" ~ R2Val), adj = 0, cex = 0.85)
```

All is good.

Comment: That doesn't work. You are missing an argument to tell `substitute` which variables to substitute. See my answer.

Comment: I've managed to paste the text in the graph with the above solution; it appears to substitute variable calls, while evaluating the plot math as it should. I'm not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Well, I've checked this on 2 machines with both R2.11-patched and R2.12-patched on Linux and your answer does not work on either. The `R2Val` is printed literally, rather than being interpreted, on the plot. I think `?substitute` is quite clear that unless you provide something for the `env` argument substitution will not take place in this example.

Comment: I've tested out the code above on my linux box as well and I think I've figured out what the difference is. Running the above code directly in the console results in the variable being printed literally (i.e., R2Val), however, when I was running the code previously, it was wrapped in a function. If you wrap the model development and plotting code in a function, it will give the desired result. In this case the environment must be implied. I do accept you answer Gavin, as it's the best way to do it. I hope this clears it up.