# Is there a way to access math symbols for plotting?

Tags: r, plot

I have a regression plot and I want to put R^2 value on my plot. Is there way to access to math symbols in R ?

Comment: Use `expression(R^2)`.  For example: `plot(1:2, 1:2, xlab=expression(R^2))`

Comment: This seems like something that would have been asked before.  [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423130/use-a-variable-within-a-plotmath-expression) is closely related.

Comment: Of you know latex, this pkg may be helpful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html

Answer (score 2):

See the help page `?plotmath`

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, type = "l")
text(4, 9, expression(R^2 == 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example which you can tailor to your needs.

```
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- 0.5 + 2 * x + rnorm(50)
model <- lm(y ~ x)
rsquared <- format(summary(model)$r.squared, digits = 3)
label <- substitute(expression(R^2 == VALUE), list(VALUE = rsquared))
png("rsquared.png")
plot(x, y)
abline(a = model$coefficients[1], b = model$coefficients[2])
legend('topleft', legend = eval(label))
```

[image]