# R / ggplot2: Evaluate object inside expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

Example code:

```
rsq <- round(cor(mtcars$disp, mtcars$mpg)^2, 2) # rsq = 0.72

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(color = "Linear")) +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = expression(paste("R"^2, " = ", rsq)))
```

I would like the legend to be displayed as `R² = 0.72`.
I know I can just use the unicode symbol for ² to get the superscript, but in general I think there has to be a way to combine math expressions and calculated values stored in objects.

I have tried to play around with `eval` and various combinations of `paste`, but it seems I keep running into the same problem.

Edit #1:
I tried using `bquote` according [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423130/use-a-variable-within-a-plotmath-expression?rq=1) like this:

`scale_color_discrete(labels = bquote(R^2 == .(rsq)))`

Turns out that only renders the legend as `==`.

Edit #2:
Even though the answer below works, it seems… very inconvenient for more complex expressions, like this:

[image]

I'm still hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out the `bquote` thing was close.
This works (although it feels… suboptimal):

```
  scale_color_discrete(labels = as.expression(bquote(R^2~"="~.(rsq))))
```

Also working:

```
 scale_color_discrete(labels = as.expression(bquote(R^2 == .(rsq))))
```

Apparently the `~` are required to "paste" the elements together, without actually `paste()`ing them? And `as.expression` does what `expression` couldn't. I'm not sure what exactly is going on, but alas, it works:

[image]

Thanks a lot, [Peter Dalgaard](https://twitter.com/pdalgd/status/708664296427888640)!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that, as of version 3.3.2 of the ggplot2 package, both `scale_color_discrete()` and `scale_color_manual()` now accept `bquote()` labels directly. Presumably this change applies more broadly to other `scale_` functions but I haven't tested more widely.

Simpler approaches like `geom_line(aes(color = bquote(...)))` and `geom_line(aes(color = as.expression(bquote(...))))` are still rejected as having invalid aesthetics, though.

```
data = data.frame(x = seq(0, 5, length.out = 50))
data$exp1 = 1 - exp(-data$x)
data$exp0.5 = 1 - exp(-0.5 * data$x)
ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) + geom_line(aes(y = exp1, color = "exp1")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = exp0.5, color = "exp0.5")) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c(bquote(1 - e^-x), bquote(1 - e^"-0.5x")), values = c("blue", "green")) + # or scale_color_discrete(labels = c(bquote(1 - e^-x), bquote(1 - e^"-0.5x")))
  labs(y = "y") + theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.15))
```

[image: ggplot with bquoted color labels]