# Subscript and evaluated variable in a ggplot title

Tags: r, ggplot2

Desired output

```
 library(ggplot2)
 data(iris)

 ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length  , y = Sepal.Width )) +
   geom_point() +
   labs(title = expression(paste('x = 30, ', y[0] , ' =  3')))
```

However, I'd like to supply the `3` from a variable. Something like

```
var <- 3
labs(title = expression(paste('x = 30, ', y[0] , ' =  ', var)))
```

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/35957129/5325862

Comment: This should do the trick: `labs(title = bquote(list(x == 30, y[0]== .(var))))`